# Cocos2d game orientation switching left->right->left directly after launch

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, uiinterfaceorientation

I'm using the default cocos2d template with slight modification to the base code.
 My game is played on left or right only- no portrait.
When the game launches, it starts right, then flips upside-down, then flips right again.
I looked through several posts on the issue and cannot seem to put my finger on what's making the interface flip back and forth without the device being moved.
 Appreciate any help!
I have the following related code:
RootViewController.m:

```
#if GAME_AUTOROTATION == kGameAutorotationUIViewController

-(void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
{
    CGRect screenRect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
    CGRect rect = CGRectZero;

    if(toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait || toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown)      
        rect = screenRect;

    else if(toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft || toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight)
        rect.size = CGSizeMake( screenRect.size.height, screenRect.size.width );

    CCDirector *director = [CCDirector sharedDirector];
    EAGLView *glView = [director openGLView];
    float contentScaleFactor = [director contentScaleFactor];

    if( contentScaleFactor != 1 ) {
        rect.size.width *= contentScaleFactor;
        rect.size.height *= contentScaleFactor;
    }
    glView.frame = rect;
}
#endif
```

AppDelegate:

```
#if GAME_AUTOROTATION == kGameAutorotationUIViewController
    [director setDeviceOrientation:kCCDeviceOrientationPortrait];
#else
    [director setDeviceOrientation:kCCDeviceOrientationLandscapeRight];
#endif
```

GameConfig.h:

```
#define kGameAutorotationNone 0
#define kGameAutorotationCCDirector 1
#define kGameAutorotationUIViewController 2

#if defined(__ARM_NEON__) || TARGET_IPHONE_SIMULATOR
#define GAME_AUTOROTATION kGameAutorotationUIViewController

#elif __arm__
#define GAME_AUTOROTATION kGameAutorotationNone
```

Comment: Please repost the code without HTML formatting, at the moment it's unreadable.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem today, it appeared to be down to the order of supported orientations in my application plist. The app would launch in Landscape Left, flip to right, then flip to left again really quickly.

I went into my project properties in the "Summary" tab (where you configure supported orientations, the app icons, launch images, etc) and deselected all the supported orientations.

I then ticked them again in order (Landscape Right, Landscape Left) - and verified in the "Info" tab that they were in this order in the array, under the "Supported Interface Orientations" section.

Item 0 - Landscape (right home button)
Item 1 - Landscape (left home button)

Not had the problem since, hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks man! you don't know how much time I've lost with this stupid thing!